# Python Newbie: using eval() to assign a value to a self.variable

Tags: python, class, eval

I am a newbie at Python and i have a class with a lot of variables, like this:

```
class trash:

    def __init__(self):
        self.var1=1
        self.var2=1
        self.var3=1
        ...

    def replaceByTwo(self, var_name)
        self.eval(var_name) = 2
```

but when i call replaceByTwo, i receive this:

```
AttributeError: 'trash' object has no attribute 'eval'
```

does anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: i'm confused... first. eval is dangerous.. but aside from that, it takes an expressing to be evaluated.. You are giving it a name that is not defined

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`eval` is a builtin not a default method for Python classes. But what you seek is `setattr`:

```
def replaceByTwo(self, var_name):
     setattr(self, var_name, 2)
```

Trial:

```
>>> t = trash()
>>> print(t.var2)
1
>>> t.replaceByTwo('var2')
>>> print(t.var2)
2
```

Answer (score 4):

the error you are getting is because you are trying to call `self.eval()`, but eval is a global function and not a member of your instance.

and anyway for what you want to do, eg set member / attribute by name, you should use `setattr()`.